# How does the thickness of a sample affect the accuracy of four-point probe resistance measurements?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I have been reading up on my experimental techniques, and I found a description of four terminal sensing [here](https://www.ossila.com/pages/sheet-resistance-theory). It makes the statement that for accurate measurement of resistance the thickness of the sample must be no more than 40% of the spacing of the contacts. Ignoring the specific limitation of 40%, why is this? Specifically, why is four terminal sensing only valid for thin samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 point resistance measurements are valid for any thickness.  What your article is talking about are measurements of sheet resistance, which is a property that can be used to calculate resistance of other geometric shapes made of the same film.  The equations they use presume that the thickness of the film is negligible compared to the distance between the contacts.  If this statement is not true, then the three dimensional effects start to matter, as we can no longer assume the voltage at any point in the volume is constant from one side of the material to the other.

Its similar in mindset to using the small angle approximation for sine.  At small angles, it works great.  Get to bigger ones, and it falls apart, and you have to use more complicated equations.

Comment: Of course, if the film is too thin, then current crowding, interface scattering, and contact resistance come into play...

Comment: Wouldn’t the problem of the contact resistance be eliminated by the four point probe?

Comment: @MaartendeHaan Contact resistance yes.  This is effects inside the film, such as "the path length to the bottom of the film across to the other electrode and back is longer than the path length across the top of the film, thus the bottom path sees a higher resistance."